# Is the git submodule name used for anything other than display?

Tags: git, git-submodules

The `.gitmodules` file used to track submodules within a git repository normally has a name for each submodule, like this:

```
[submodule "my-submodule"]
  path = foo/bar/my-submodule
  url = http://github.com/myuser/original-my-submodule
```

However, I've also seen it written with the local path duplicated in the submodule name:

```
[submodule "foo/bar/my-submodule"]
  path = foo/bar/my-submodule
  url = http://github.com/myuser/original-my-submodule
```

I have both of these styles in one of my repositories, probably by accident, and I'm not sure why they are different.

I'd like to make sure I have these expressed correctly. Which of these is "correct"? Does it matter? Is the submodule name used for anything other than display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`gitmodules` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules) includes:

> The file contains one subsection per submodule, and the subsection value is the name of the submodule.
>   **The name is set to the path where the submodule has been added unless it was customized with the `--name` option of `git submodule add`**.

It is then possible that a submodule is added (`git submodule add`) twice, with and without the `--name` option ("without" means: its default "name" used in the .gitmodules is its path, like `foo/bar/my-submodule`).

It doesn't seem to matter to [`git submodule add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), since it is generally used with the `--name` option as well, using one of the two entries of the `.gitmodules`.
A git submodule add without `--name` would use the second entry of the `.gitmodules`.

If both url are the same in those two entries... the result of `git submodule add` command is the same.
Beside 'add', the name isn't used elsewhere.

Comment: OK, so that would probably explain why I have both styles (although I don't recall using `--name`). But it sounds like you're saying it really doesn't matter much, the name isn't used except for display (e.g. `git-submodule status`)?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier As far as I know, the name is only used for `git submodule add`

Comment: I'm sorry, you're quite correct. I just checked and `git-submodule status` just shows the pathname to the module, not this name. How odd for it to store such write-only information.

Answer (score 1):

Settings in `.git/config` use the name.

For example if you want to avoid checkout of the submodule during the `git submodule update` you have to edit the `.git/config` like that:

```
git config submodule.my-submodule-name.update '!true'
```

(I'm writing this just because I'm annoyed that I have to deal with the name in addition to the path)